AppExchange Application
As a salesforce partner we are going to upload a managed package to AppExchange. We need to update our codebase and upload it to apply. I tried using the code analyzer, but the topics were very limited, so I couldn't fully understand what to do or how to fix the issues. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Also, when uploading the package, should I pay special attention to security review? What other aspects should I consider? I'd appreciate any advice.

Be aware that typically multiple submissions are needed to get an app through the security review - hard to get it right first time - so expect this process to take multiple weeks/months of elapsed time. But the pay-off for you is re-assurance for your customers that your app has been through a serious security review process.


I tried using the code analyzer, but the topics were very limited [...]

You'll want to read all of the documentation. Salesforce has documented quite a bit, you just need to know where to look.

I couldn't fully understand what to do or how to fix the issues.

If you have any specific questions about various errors and warnings, please search our extensive list of questions before asking; whatever problems you have encountered are almost guaranteed to have happened to someone else before, and should be found here. If, after doing a search, you can't seem to find the answer, just ask a question. We'll be happy to point you to specific resources.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Yes. There are lots of consultants out there that would be happy to help, possibly for free, or a nominal fee. And, of course, we'll be happy to answer any questions or point you to relevant resources.

Also, when uploading the package, should I pay special attention to security review?

Yes. You want to pass the security review. Until you do, your potential clients will receive a huge warning on the installation page that the app may be unsecure (with the implication of being untrusted). You should be prepared to address every issue, and provide a document for any false positives.

What other aspects should I consider?

The security review only considers security concerns and some critical performance problems (e.g. queries inside a loop). It is still your responsibility to make sure that the application has proper error handling, doesn't crash frequently, and is free of logic bugs.
These are things that no automated scanner available currently looks for, aside from ApexPMD, which mostly focuses on code quality and performance problems that would be flagged by the other automated scanners (e.g. queries in a loop).
They don't identify things like using variables before they're assigned a value, etc. Make sure you have appropriate unit testing for both Apex and any Aura/LWC components you've written. A program that crashes frequently or doesn't handle errors properly will only frustrate your clients.
